# Size of background images to support all medium and large android screens

Tags: android, background, dpi, resolutions

I'm writing an app and I want one of my activities to have a background,

I've read the android docs about supporting multiple resolutions etc,
but my designer is asking me what size the wallpapers should be and I do not want a lot of images for low,normal,high dpi in all the screen sizes.

What would be the most space efficient way to get a nice screen filling graphic background on all those screens?

Android is great and all, but I do not want to end up with a huge app since I need all sizes of images for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to design for the densities and use the [Icon Design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) for icons, and the dimensions specified in the "[Range of Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range)" area in the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) guide for your background images.

For the background images be sure to take the status bar dimensions into consideration.

You can put your resources in the appropriate drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi folders and they will be used appropriately.

Comment: that would mean that I would need 5 differently sized wallpapers (not writing for small screen), I'm not displaying the status bar since it's a game.

Comment: I'm assuming since it's a game, you are only doing landscape. You would only need 1 for mdpi which would be 480x320 ... 2 for hdpi, 800x480 and 854x480 ... so 3 in total

Answer (score 0):

What about having only one high resolution landscape background and using a "stretch" strategy for display?

```
    mBackgroundGraphic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
    mBackgroundGraphic = getResizedBitmap(mBackgroundGraphic);

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    int displayWidth = mDisplay.getWidth();
    int displayHeight = mDisplay.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) displayWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) displayHeight) / height;

    // Create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // Resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // Return the new stretched Bitmap
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
}
```